# about weight decomposition of U(sl3)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, weights

the universal enveloping algebra is  $\mathbb{Z}^2$-graded algebra. $U(sl_3)=  \bigoplus_{(i_1,i_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 } U_{i_1\alpha_1+i_2\alpha_2}$ $($the weight decomposition$)$ where $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the simple roots of $sl_3(K)$. 
Is there a book that explain this decomposition?